# Activity or Fragment Activity

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am confused to built an app either extending Activity or Fragment Activity using FaceBook SDK. Before Facebook SDK 3.0 I was used normal activity to built the User Interface. But I saw the examples provided by the FaceBook SDK, they use Fragment Activity. I am not so familiar with this. Also I saw somewhere people use native SDK/libraries like **Easy Facebook Android SDK**, **FbRocket**, **FbConnect** to built apps.

So,Please Somebody can guide me, Which sdk should I use ? and also share us the differences between Activity or Fragment Activity. I wanna also learn fragment in android if it needs to built good one.

Any link or suggestion appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FragmentActivity is the part of android support v4 lib. It allows to use Fragments feature on android version prior 3.x. If you need fragments in your application you may use it.

Comment: can give an example where to use fragment. Don't know either its needed or not.

Comment: Fragment is a part of view which can be reused so it is much more flexible to use than just using plain activities http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Thanks for your guide. After reading the tutorial on FB Developers with full concentration I understand the fragment & also FaceBook new SDK.